# How to add if(A and B) then C constraints in Gurobi

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, gurobi

Now I have three 5 by 3 matrix, X, Y, Z. All elements in them are binary variables. I want to add the following constraints:

[image]

I know I should introduce an auxiliary binary variable here. But I really stuck in how to write these simple conditional equalities as linear constraints. Any advice, tricks, suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need extra binary variables for this.

```
x(i,j)=1 and x(i+1,j)=0 => z(i+1,j)=1
```

can be interpreted as:

```
z(i+1,j) >= x(i,j)*(1-x(i+1,j))
```

This can be written as a linear inequality:

```
z(i+1,j) >= x(i,j) - x(i+1,j)
```

Similarly,

```
x(i,j)=0 and x(i+1,j)=1 => y(i+1,j)=1
```

can be formulated as:

```
y(i+1,j) >= x(i+1,j) - x(i,j)
```